# How to re-render only a single layer on a mapcanvas?

Tags: qgis, c++, api, mapcanvas

In my application I have a mapcanvas that contains several layers.
some of layers need to be updated or rendered again because data has been changed ( like the geometry or some attributes )

Is there another way to update only one layer in a mapcanvas ?

My previous search is setLayerSet
actually i use the setLayerSet but all of the layer are rendered again,

I am working in c++ / §QT 4.8.5 and qgis api c++ 2.8.2

Comment: Hi, it seems that you are mixing two questions here. I assume that you are actually interested in re-rendering only a single layer and now have a suspicion that it *could* be related to `setLayerSet`? If yes, please reformulate your question (and title) and mention `setLayerSet` as "previous research". It will help to give you an answer to your real problem.

Comment: ok i change the title and the question

Comment: hum perhaps i found in the topics 66075 something interresting , i will try it tomorrow

Comment: in fact in this post (66075) it is only for the order of the rendering, what i need is to re-render only one layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do requires two things to work properly.

1. You have to enable caching for the map canvas (once, on initialization)
2. You will have to request a repaint of the layer in question (whenever you want to repaint it)

## Enable caching

By default a new `QgsMapCanvas` will be initialized with caching disabled. To enable it do

```
mapCanvas->setCachingEnabled( true );
```

## Request a repaint

To request a repaint for a particular layer, you will have to call its `triggerRepaint()` method. This method is defined on `QgsMapLayer` level, so it works the same for raster layers.

```
mapLayer->triggerRepaint();
```

This method is a slot and therefore can also be connected to a signal if this makes things easier.

```
connect( myObject, SIGNAL( thingsHaveChanged() ), mapLayer, SLOT( triggerRepaint() ) );
```

Comment: for the signal can i use layerschanged() of the class qgsmapcanvas or is it better to use the datachanged() of the class qgsmaplayer

Comment: You better provide your own signal which is emitted according to your business logic. Abuse of existing signals always bears the risk of undesired secondary effects.

Comment: I only put the cache to true and it works !!! my vectorlayer move on the screen without re-render all the canvas and without call the triggerrepaint!!! There is something i don't understand if i need to call triggerrepaint for the layer why does it work without call the function ? doaes the fact that i call setlayerset do the same thing

Comment: Yes it does call the same internally, but `setLayerSet` isn't meant to do this. So it may do other things which you do not need and it is possible that in a future version it will change its behavior (e.g. clear the cache when it's called...). You better switch to calling `triggerRepaint` and only call `setLayerSet` when you add or remove a layer.